# Merge rows with different data

Tags: stata

I have the following dataset in Stata:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input id price weight length str3(origin destination)
1 2763 . 34 "AUS" "USA"
2 . 234 28 "" "GER"
1 2763 543 . "." "USA"
2 8976 . 28 "ESP" "GER"
3 . 112 . "ARG" "POL"
3 1256 112 . "ARG" "POL"
3 1256 112 66 "." "."
4 6789 . 16 "UK" ""
2 8976 . . "ESP" ""
4 . 452 16 "." "CAN"
end
```

This contains different data for different entries in different rows.

How can I merge everything in a single entry to get the output below:

```
1 2763 543 34 "AUS" "USA"
2 8976 234 28 "ESP" "GER"
3 1256 112 66 "ARG" "POL"
4 6789 452 16 "UK"  "CAN"
```

Comment: If you have an identifier, the solution is similar to the answer i gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377373/)

Comment: No, that's all there is in the dataset. But the information is fragmented in different rows.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a general solution then. There is no way to know which rows belong to each entry.

Comment: Can you help me with the case where the id variable is known? I will try to create this variable by hand.

Comment: You just use the code from my answer to the linked question and then run the command `duplicates drop`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in two steps:

1. Generate several group variables based on id, or price, or anything that has little missing values. For example, generate a group_1 variable based on id. Sort and rank all data based on this variable.
2. Use xfill command to fill the missing values within a group.

You need to repeat these two steps with different id variables constructed from different underlying variables, depending on the exact dataset.